# Pause menu, health bar is not pausing

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I press escape button,my game paused and gui shows but my health bar at canvas does not pause.. here is my code.. any suggestions

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {
bool paused = false;
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("pauseButton"))
        paused = togglePause();
}
void OnGUI()
{
    if(paused)
    {
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-        100,Screen.height/2+1,180,40),"Resume Game"))
            paused = togglePause();
    }
}
bool togglePause()
{
    if(Time.timeScale == 0f)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        return(false);
    }
    else
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        return(true);    
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @Programmer kindly help me out

Comment: When you say that your health bar is not "pausing" what does that mean? Is the health bar moving?

Comment: like my player goes into fire and health bar is decreasing, so at time if I pressed pause button then along with screen, health bar must be paused, but health bar does not paused and continue to decrease

Comment: Show as that code. `Time.timeScale = 0` doesn't stop everything.

Comment: What will be solution? @GunnarB.
I didn't get you.. :-(

Comment: Why it doesn't stopping everything?

Comment: If it would stop everything your game would freeze and be completly unresponsive. If your damaging is called e.g. in `Update` and doesn't use `Time.deltaTime` it will still be called. So to actually be able to help you we need to know how you did the stuff that is not getting paused.

Comment: Exactly my damaging functionality is in update function, thanks now I get the direction :-)

Comment: @GunnarB. post this comment in answer, i will accept it. it really help me out Thanks Alot :-)

Comment: I simply used time.delta in my damaging functionality in update function; Cheers

Comment: I did that. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time.timeScale = 0` doesn't stop everything.

If it would stop everything your game would freeze and be completly unresponsive. If your damaging is called e.g. in `Update` and doesn't use `Time.deltaTime` it will still be called.